# Longest Repeated Substring Issue

Tags: algorithm, suffix-tree

When creating a suffix tree of the string "ABAB" I get only 2 nodes:

ABAB and BAB

The longest repeatead substring ("AB") should be located by "the deepest node with at least k descendants" but this is not the case with my string, what's wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: That is not a correct suffix tree (e.g. it doesn't have the suffix "B" anywhere).

Comment: Yet it has, it has any of the suffixes of "ABAB" and "BAB" (it uses path compression)

Comment: No, it doesn't. If you think it does, show the actual suffix tree, and where you find the suffix "B" on it.

Comment: The suffix B is included in the BAB leaf, you can run it yourself using Mark Nelson's program (http://marknelson.us/1996/08/01/suffix-trees/) I think The anwser to my question is that I need to count the occurences of each letter.

Comment: I don't understand how you could extract all suffixes from that representation (By your reasoning you could also say that "ABA" is included in the "ABAB" leaf, but ABA is not a suffix). My answer shows the representation that is probably intended by this algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using some form of suffix tree which has only two nodes for the string ABAB, then it won't work directly with the algorithm you quoted. This is what the suffix tree should look like, with `O` representing the nodes and `$` used to mark the end of the string.

```
         O
        / \
       /   \
      B     AB
     /       \
    O         O
   / \       / \
  $  AB$    $  AB$
 /     \   /     \
O       O O       O
```

The key feature here (and which is missing from the tree you are using) is that each leaf node corresponds to a suffix of the string.

The deepest node with at least two leaf descendants is at path AB (the depth is the substring length needed to reach that node from the root, in this case 2), and that is indeed the longest repeated substring.

Comment: You can compile and run Mark's example (C++) or just use the online suffix tree (http://www.allisons.org/ll/AlgDS/Tree/Suffix/) and still you'll get ABAB and BAB

Comment: @kukit: What's your point? That would still give a useless tree (for this algorithm) since it doesn't actually represent suffixes. If you explicitly add an end-of-string marker (i.e. run your algorithm on "ABAB$") you should get a correct tree.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying "depth".  I had previously interpreted it as just the number of edges, and ignored the length of the string.